# Conditionally Select additional rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, case

I have two tables:

```
TableA
PK      Alpha    Critter   Etc 
1        A      zebra     apple
2        C      lion      orange
3        R      giraffe   banana
4        D      gopher    pear

TableC
PK      Alpha   Animal    Misc
1       D       beaver    kiwi
2       D       camel     avacado
```

I need this result:

```
Result
PK      Alpha    Critter  Etc
22      A       zebra    apple
23      C       lion     orange
24      R       giraffe  banana
25      D       gopher   pear
26      D       beaver   kiwi
27      D       camel    avacado
```

If the value of TableA.Alpha equals more than one TableC.Alpha with the same value the 
Select would be:

```
Select TA.Alpha, TA.Critter, TA.Etc
From TableA TA
```

and

```
Select TC.Alpha, TC.Animal, TC.Misc
From TableC TC
```

on separate rows (3 rows in the above example)

Otherwise it is just

```
Select TA.Alpha, TA.Critter, TA.Etc
From TableA TA
```

(one row)

I might use CTE. Something like:

```
With T_CTE (Alpha,CountAlpha)
AS
(SELECT 
TC. Alpha, COUNT(TC.Alpha) as CountAlpha
FROM TableC TC
GROUP BY TC.Alpha
HAVING (COUNT(TC.Alpha) > 1 ))

Select TA.Alpha, TA.Critter, TA.Etc
From TableA TA
case when T_CTE.Alpha is not null then...else...end
left join T_CTE on T_CTE.Alpha = TA.Alpha
```

TableA.Alpha is unique. TableC.Alpha is not unique.

Am I able to call another select for addtional rows? Is there a better approach? I've also thought of creating temp tables and selecting from them.
This is part of a larger query, but I want to focus on this part now.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: "TableA.Alpha equals more than one TableC.Alpha"  Do you mean for each value of PK? Your example just looks like a `UNION`

Comment: I meant for each value of PK in TableA. Alpha in TableA is unique. Alpha is not unique in TableC. I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
;with cte as (
  select A.Alpha, count(*) as cnt
  from TableA as A
      inner join TableC as C on C.Alpha = A.Alpha
  group by A.Alpha
  having count(*) > 1
)
select A.Alpha, A.Critter, A.Etc
from TableA as A
union all
select C.Alpha, C.Animal, C.Misc
from TableC as C
where C.Alpha in (select T.Alpha from cte as T)
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb2a4/1) - I've added one row to TableC to check if it would include it

Comment: Thanks. That should work. I have to work it into a much larger query. I'll post another reply later.